# M-Tab not working with icomplete

Tags: icomplete

I am currently looking into *icomplete*, and the manual states

```
‘M-<TAB>’ will select the first completion in the list, like ‘C-j’
but without exiting the minibuffer, so you can edit it further.
```

However, that does not work for me. Instead, M-Tab is bound to *complete-symbol*. I thought that this is because I had bound M-Tab somewhere in my Emacs init file, but that is not the case.

So I tried to rebind the command to another key, and I believed the correct command is *icomplete-force-complete*, but that does not seem to work. When I issue this command in the minibuffer with icomplete active, I only get

```
[File Cache: no match]
```

even though there are various completions available.

So my question is, how can I get the described behavior of selecting the first item in the completion list to edit it further?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *fido-mode* must be enabled, too for M-Tab to work (even though it is listed as an “alternative” to icomplete).